# Most efficient way to batch delete S3 Files

Tags: amazon-s3, batch-processing

I'd like to be able to batch delete thousands or tens of thousands of files at a time on S3. Each file would be anywhere from 1MB to 50MB. Naturally, I don't want the user (or my server) to be waiting while the files are in the process of being deleted.  Hence, the questions:

1. How does S3 handle file deletion, especially when deleting large numbers of files?
2. Is there an efficient way to do this and make AWS do most of the work?  By efficient, I mean by making the least number of requests to S3 and taking the least amount of time using the least amount of resources on my servers.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

AWS supports bulk deletion of up to 1000 objects per request using the S3 REST API and its various wrappers. This method assumes you know the S3 object keys you want to remove (that is, it's not designed to handle something like a retention policy, files that are over a certain size, etc).

The S3 REST API can specify up to 1000 files to be deleted in a single request, which is must quicker than making individual requests. Remember, each request is an HTTP (thus TCP) request. So each request carries overhead. You just need to know the objects' keys and create an HTTP request (or use an wrapper in your language of choice). [AWS provides great information on this feature and its usage](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/DeletingMultipleObjects.html). Just choose the method you're most comfortable with!

I'm assuming your use case involves end users specifying a number of specific files to delete at once. Rather than initiating a task such as "purge all objects that refer to picture files" or "purge all files older than a certain date" (which I believe is easy to configure separately in S3).

If so, you'll know the keys that you need to delete. It also means the user will like more real time feedback about whether their file was deleted successfully or not. References to exact keys are supposed to be very quick, since S3 was designed to scale efficiently despite handling an extremely large amount of data.

If not, you can look into asynchronous API calls. You can read a bit about how they'd work in general from this [blog post](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/php/post/Tx3RR28K9AAHPD1/Version-3-Preview-of-the-AWS-SDK) or search for how to do it in the language of your choice. This would allow the deletion request to take up its own thread, and the rest of the code can execute without making a user wait. Or, you could offload the request to a queue . . . But both of these options needlessly complicate either your code (asynchronous code can be annoying) or your environment (you'd need a service/daemon/container/server to handle the queue. So I'd avoid this scenario if possible.

Edit: I don't have the reputation to post more than 2 links. But you can see Amazon's comments on request rate and performance here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/request-rate-perf-considerations.html And the s3 faq comments that bulk deleiton is the way to go if possible.

Answer (score 47):

The *excruciatingly slow* option is `s3 rm --recursive` if you actually like waiting.

Running parallel `s3 rm --recursive` with differing `--include` patterns is slightly faster but a lot of time is still spent waiting, as each process individually fetches the entire key list in order to locally perform the `--include` pattern matching.

**Enter bulk deletion.**

I found I was able to get the most speed by deleting 1000 keys at a time using [`aws s3api delete-objects`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/delete-objects.html).

Here's an example:

```
cat file-of-keys | xargs -P8 -n1000 bash -c 'aws s3api delete-objects --bucket MY_BUCKET_NAME --delete "Objects=[$(printf "{Key=%s}," "$@")],Quiet=true"' _
```

- The `-P8` option on `xargs` controls the parallelism.  It's eight in this case, meaning 8 instances of 1000 deletions at a time.
- The `-n1000` option tells `xargs` to bundle 1000 keys for each `aws s3api delete-objects` call.
- Removing `,Quiet=true` or changing it to `false` will spew out server responses.
- Note:  There's an easily missed `_` at the end of that command line.  @VladNikiforov posted an [excellent commentary of what it's for in the comment](https://serverfault.com/questions/679989#comment1210678_917740) so I'm going to just link to that.

**But how do you get `file-of-keys`?**

If you already have your list of keys, good for you.  Job complete.

If not, here's one way I guess:

```
aws s3 ls "s3://MY_BUCKET_NAME/SOME_SUB_DIR" | sed -nre "s|[0-9-]+ [0-9:]+ +[0-9]+ |SOME_SUB_DIR|p" >file-of-keys
```

Comment: Great approach, but I found that listing the keys was the bottleneck. This is much faster:

`aws s3api list-objects --output text --bucket BUCKET --query 'Contents[].[Key]' | pv -l > BUCKET.keys`

And then removing objects (this was sufficient that going over 1 parallel process reaches the rate limits for object deletion):

`tail -n+0 BUCKET.keys | pv -l | grep -v -e "'" | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 -P1 -n1000 bash -c 'aws s3api delete-objects --bucket BUCKET --delete "Objects=[$(printf "{Key=%q}," "$@")],Quiet=true"' _`

Comment: You probably should also have stressed the importance on `_` in the end :) I missed it and then it took me quite a while to understand why the first element gets skipped. The point is that `bash -c` passes all arguments as positional parameters, starting with `$0`, while "$@" only processes parameters starting with `$1`. So the underscore dummy is needed to fill the position of `$0`.

Comment: @VladNikiforov Cheers, edited.

Comment: One problem I've found with this approach (either from antak or Vlad) is that it's not easily resumable if there's an error. If you are deleting a lot keys (10M in my case) you may have a network error, or throttling error, that breaks this. So to improve this, I've used `split -l 1000` to split my keys file into 1000 key batches. Now for each file I can issue the delete command then delete the file. If anything goes wrong, I can continue.

Comment: If you just want al list of the keys, I would think `aws s3 ls "s3://MY_BUCKET_NAME/SOME_SUB_DIR" | awk '{print $4}'` would be simpler and you can add a `| grep` to filter that down from there.

Comment: Man doing this with millions of objects really sucks, but thanks to all of you for the pointers. I used the split command to to split into 10k key files, then used SEK's command to run them with some parallelism. Then also deleting the split files when completed to offer some checkpointing. I found 10 threads to give me warnings to slow down from AWS. I'm going with 4 at the moment and it's going well.

Comment: For aws cli v2, disabling the pager helps when running the s3api delete-objects command: export AWS_PAGER=""

Answer (score 19):

A neat trick is using lifecycle rules to handle the delete for you. You can queue a rule to delete the prefix or objects that you want and Amazon will just take care of the deletion.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/create-lifecycle.html

Comment: Be careful, though, as this can be very expensive if you have a lot of objects, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54255990/cheapest-way-to-delete-2-billion-objects-from-s3-ia

Comment: DeleteObject and DeleteObjects requests and lifecycle policies sending those requests are all free regardless of the number of objects. The expense your link refers to is from early deletion fees for non-standard storage classes which have minimum billable storage durations.

Comment: This is the best answer. Very fast and no cost. You do have to wait for the lifecycle rule to run, which happens once per day.

Answer (score 6):

### One liner batching w/ S3API

Here is my one liner based on other responses to this post.

1. Gets a batch of 1000 S3 object keys (without needing to save them to a file)
2. Pipes the keys to the delete command
3. Two delete commands are initiated in parallel for 500 objects each

```
aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket $BUCKET --prefix $PREFIX --output text --query \
'Contents[].[Key]' | grep -v -e "'" | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 -P2 -n500 bash -c \
'aws s3api delete-objects --bucket $BUCKET --delete "Objects=[$(printf "{Key=%q}," "$@")],Quiet=true"' _
```

#### Why no keys file?

One of the complaints about piping the keys to a file was that errors could happen while deleting from s3. If you had to restart the delete command, you would have a file with lots of keys that are already deleted and you would waste time running the delete commands again.

#### Why 2 delete commands?

I tried to delete all 1000 objects with 1 delete command. I would get an error the my argument list was too long (because I have long keys)

Comment: This is an incredibly fast method (minutes vs days in my case).  Note that since $BUCKET is used in a sub-shell, it must be **exported**, not just **set** : `export BUCKET=XXXX`

Answer (score 5):

I was frustrated by the performance of the web console for this task. I found that the [AWS CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) command does this well. For example:

`aws s3 rm --recursive s3://my-bucket-name/huge-directory-full-of-files`

For a large file hierarchy, this may take some considerable amount of time. You can set this running in a `tmux` or `screen` session and check back later.

Comment: It looks like the `aws s3 rm --recursive` command deletes files individually.  Although faster than the web console, when deleting lots of files, it could be much faster if it deleted in bulk

Answer (score 5):

There already mention about [`s3 sync`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html) command before, but without example and word about `--delete` option.

I found it fastest way to delete content of folder in `S3` bucket `my_bucket` by:

```
aws s3 sync --delete "local-empty-dir/" "s3://my_bucket/path-to-clear"
```

Comment: Not the fastest way, but the easiest to apply. For the record, that's how I use it: `parallel -j 40 -N0 'aws s3 sync "." "s3://my-bucket/path/to/clear/"' ::: {1..40}`

Answer (score 3):

I know this post is really old at this point but if you're having to do this today, the AWS dashboard now has an "Empty" feature on the bucket search page which will perform a bulk delete (1000 at a time) for you:

[image: Image of AWS Dashboard - S3 Empty Button Highlighted]

Comment: I've tried different ways and looks like this option works best for me! Emptied my bucket with ~100k files and ~50GB in size in minutes.

Answer (score 1):

I found rclone to be pretty fast as it uses the S3 API.

https://rclone.org/

`rclone delete --progress --transfers=1000 <rclone_confg>:<s3_bucket_and_prefix>`

Answer (score 1):

There is a way in Python that uses botos'3 delete_objects, tqdm to give a bit of feedback, and multiple threads to give it a little bit of parallelism (in spite of the GIL, multiple requests to S3 should run at the same time)

This is at https://gist.github.com/michalc/20b79c9028c342ef7c38df8693f8715b but to copy it here:

```python
# From some light testing deletes at between 2000 to 6000 objects per second, and works best if you
# have objects distributed into folders/CommonPrefixes as specified by the delimiter.

from concurrent.futures import FIRST_EXCEPTION, ThreadPoolExecutor, wait
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from functools import partial
from typing import Callable, Optional, Tuple
from queue import PriorityQueue

import boto3


def bulk_delete(
    bucket, prefix,
    workers=8, page_size=1000, delimiter='/',
    get_s3_client=lambda: boto3.client('s3'), on_delete=lambda num: None,
):
    s3 = get_s3_client()
    queue = PriorityQueue()

    @dataclass(order=True)
    class Work:
        # A tuple that determines the priority of the bit of work in "func". This is a sort of
        # "coordinate" in the paginated node tree that prioritises a depth-first search.
        priority: Tuple[Tuple[int,int], ...]
        # The work function itself that fetches a page of Key/CommonPrefixes, or deletes
        func: Optional[Callable[[], None]] = field(compare=False)

    # A sentinal "stop" Work instance with priority chosen to be before all work. So when it's
    # queued the workers will stop at the very next opportunity
    stop = Work(((-1,-1),), None)

    def do_work():
        while (work := queue.get()) is not stop:
            work.func()
            queue.task_done()
            with queue.mutex:
                unfinished_tasks = queue.unfinished_tasks
            if unfinished_tasks == 0:
                for _ in range(0, workers):
                    queue.put(stop)

    def list_iter(prefix):
        return iter(s3.get_paginator('list_objects_v2').paginate(
            Bucket=bucket, Prefix=prefix,
            Delimiter=delimiter, MaxKeys=page_size, PaginationConfig={'PageSize': page_size},
        ))

    def delete_page(page):
        s3.delete_objects(Bucket=bucket, Delete={'Objects': page})
        on_delete(len(page))

    def process_page(page_iter, priority):
        try:
            page = next(page_iter)
        except StopIteration:
            return

        # Deleting a page is done at the same priority as this function. It will often be done
        # straight after this call because this call must have been the highest priority for it to
        # have run, but there could be unfinished nodes earlier in the depth-first search that have
        # since submitted work, and so would be prioritised over the deletion
        if contents := page.get('Contents'):
            delete_priority = priority
            queue.put(Work(
                priority=delete_priority,
                func=partial(delete_page, [{'Key': obj['Key']} for obj in contents]),
            ))

        # Processing child prefixes are done after deletion and in order. Importantly anything each
        # child prefix itself enqueues should be done before the work of any later child prefixes
        # to make it a depth-first search. Appending the index of the child prefix to the priority
        # tuple of this function does this, because the work inside each child prefix will only
        # ever enqueue work at its priority or greater, but always less than the priority of
        # subsequent child prefixes or the next page.
        for prefix_index, obj in enumerate(page.get('CommonPrefixes', [])):
            prefix_priority = priority + ((prefix_index,0),)
            queue.put(Work(
                priority=prefix_priority,
                func=partial(process_page,
                             page_iter=list_iter(obj['Prefix']), priority=prefix_priority)
            ))

        # The next page in pagination for this prefix is processed after delete for this page,
        # after all the child prefixes are processed, and after anything the child prefixes
        # themselves enqueue.
        next_page_priority = priority[:-1] + ((priority[-1][0], priority[-1][1] + 1),)
        queue.put(Work(
            priority=next_page_priority,
            func=partial(process_page, page_iter=page_iter, priority=next_page_priority),
        ))

    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=workers) as worker_pool:
        # Bootstrap with the first page
        priority = ((0,0),)
        queue.put(Work(
            priority=priority,
            func=partial(process_page, page_iter=list_iter(prefix), priority=priority),
        ))

        # Run workers, waiting for the first exception, if any, raised by them
        done, _ = wait(
            tuple(worker_pool.submit(do_work) for _ in range(0, workers)),
            return_when=FIRST_EXCEPTION,
        )

        # If an exception raised, stop all the other workers because otherwise exiting the
        # ThreadPoolExecutor context will block, and re-raise the exception
        if e := next(iter(done)).exception():
            for _ in range(0, workers - 1):
                queue.put(stop)
            raise e from None
```

used as:

```python
from tqdm import tqdm

print('Deleting...')
with tqdm(unit=' objects') as pbar:
    bulk_delete(
        bucket='my-bucket', prefix='my-prefix/',
        on_delete=lambda num: pbar.update(num),
    )
print('Done')
```

As the gist suggests, it seems to delete at a rate between 2000 and 6000 objects per second, which from my testing is better than plain delete_objects without multiple threads. But your milage may vary.

It works by walking the tree of CommonPrefixes (folder-like structures in S3), and paginating through objects in them, but walking and deleting multiple branches of the tree at the same time. So it should give a performance benefit over plain pagination + delete_objects with no threads if there is a good amount of such CommonPrefixes, and there is a good amount of objects per CommonPrefix.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing how you're managing the s3 buckets, this may or may not be particularly useful.

The AWS CLI tools has an option called "sync" which can be particularly effective to ensure s3 has the correct objects.  If you, or your users, are managing S3 from a local filesystem, you may be able to save a ton of work determining which objects need to be deleted by using the CLI tools.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html

Answer (score 0):

I made a python script for this.

***P.S. it nukes your account s3, all buckets.***

```
import concurrent.futures
import boto3

def purge_bucket(Bucket, S3Client):
    response = S3Client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=Bucket)
    while 'Contents' in response and response['KeyCount'] > 0:
        for key in response['Contents']:
            value = key['Key']
            key.clear()
            key['Key'] = value
        print(f'Deleting {len(response["Contents"])} keys at {Bucket}')
        out = S3Client.delete_objects(
            Bucket=Bucket, 
            Delete={'Objects': response['Contents']}
        )
        if 'Errors' in out:
            print(f'Errors at {Bucket}: {out["Errors"]}')
        response = S3Client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=Bucket)
    return Bucket

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
response = s3.list_buckets()
if len(response['Buckets']) > 0:
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        runs = []
        for bucket in response['Buckets']:
            bucket = bucket['Name']
            runs.append(executor.submit(purge_bucket, Bucket=bucket, S3Client=s3))
        for run in concurrent.futures.as_completed(runs):
            try:
                end = s3.delete_bucket(Bucket=run.result())
                print(end)
            except Exception as e:
                print(f'{run.result()}: {e}')
```